# Exchange Web Services Schema Validation Error

Tags: xml, soap, xsd, exchange-server, exchangewebservices

I'm sending a SOAP request to Exchange Web Services but I'm getting an error response back from the server. It seems to point to a schema validation issue, something wrong in my request. However, this request works fine in Exchange 2016 but doesn't seem to work in Exchange 2007.

This is my request to .../EWS/Exchange.asmx:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" xmlns:ns2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages">
  <SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <ns1:RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2007_SP1" />
  </SOAP-ENV:Header>
  <SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <ns2:FindItem Traversal="Shallow">
      <ns2:ItemShape>
        <ns1:BaseShape>AllProperties</ns1:BaseShape>
        <ns1:AdditionalProperties>
          <ns1:ExtendedFieldURI PropertySetId="c2dd7db7-7f7f-42cf-bbf7-7384836b0c89" PropertyName="CRMID" PropertyType="Integer" />
        </ns1:AdditionalProperties>
      </ns2:ItemShape>
      <ns2:Restriction>
        <ns1:Or>
          <ns1:IsEqualTo>
            <ns1:ExtendedFieldURI PropertySetId="c2dd7db7-7f7f-42cf-bbf7-7384836b0c89" PropertyName="CRMID" PropertyType="Integer" />
            <ns1:FieldURIOrConstant>
              <ns1:Constant Value="11290" />
            </ns1:FieldURIOrConstant>
          </ns1:IsEqualTo>
        </ns1:Or>
      </ns2:Restriction>
      <ns2:ParentFolderIds>
        <ns1:DistinguishedFolderId Id="calendar" />
      </ns2:ParentFolderIds>
    </ns2:FindItem>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

This is the response I'm getting:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<soap11:Envelope xmlns:soap11="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soap11:Header>
        <t:ServerVersionInfo MajorVersion="8" MinorVersion="1" MajorBuildNumber="436" MinorBuildNumber="0" xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types" />
    </soap11:Header>
    <soap11:Body>
        <soap11:Fault>
            <faultcode>soap11:Client</faultcode>
            <faultstring>The request failed schema validation: The element 'Or' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types' has incomplete content. List of possible elements expected: 'SearchExpression' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types'.</faultstring>
            <detail>
                <e:ResponseCode xmlns:e="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/errors">ErrorSchemaValidation</e:ResponseCode>
                <e:Message xmlns:e="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/errors">The element 'Or' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types' has incomplete content. List of possible elements expected: 'SearchExpression' in namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types'.</e:Message>
                <e:Line xmlns:e="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/errors">22</e:Line>
                <e:Position xmlns:e="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/errors">11</e:Position>
            </detail>
        </soap11:Fault>
    </soap11:Body>
</soap11:Envelope>
```

I'm having trouble finding any information about the http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types namespace and I don't know what to change in my request for it to work correctly.

Does anyone know how I can change my request to resolve the error?

Comment: Even without knowing anything about the schema, I would expect an "Or" element to require two (or more?) children. But why are you trying to construct a request using an XML vocabulary that you are having trouble finding information about? Trying to get this working by trial and error seems an inefficient process.

Comment: Hi, I am using the following library: https://github.com/jamesiarmes/php-ews which is currently maintained. I'll go with your theory requiring the "Or" two have at least two or more children and see what happens.

Comment: Which part of "`The element 'Or' in namespace [... 2006/types] has incomplete content. List of possible elements expected: 'SearchExpression' in namespace [... 2006/types]`" seems unclear to you?

Comment: I don't know what the incomplete content is, and I can't find any information about what that incomplete content is nor is there any official documentation that I can follow. As I say, I'm just using a PHP EWS library so don't have the experience with EWS to know what the fault is.